# How to input value from user using structure pointer and display the value of structure members?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct employee
{
   int id;
   char name[20];
   float salary;
   char addr[];   
}*emp;

void get_emp(struct employee **record)
{

   printf("\tplease enter details of employee:\n");

   printf("id= ");
    scanf("%d",(*record)->id);//code to get input value

   printf("Name= ");
   scanf(" %s",(*record)->name);

   printf("salary= ");
   scanf("%f",(*record)->salary);


}

int main()
{
get_emp(&emp);
printf("id=%d\n",emp->id); // code to display the value
printf("Name=%s\n",emp->name);
printf("salary=%f\n",emp->salary);


return 0;
}
```

I have a structure example and I want to pass structure pointer to the function without using normal variable but only pointer. Is the parameter(double pointer) in the function **get_emp(struct employee **record)** a correct way to do if not what changes should be made? Also how to get input value from users in the function **get_emp(struct employee **record)** and how to display the value?

Comment: You haven't compiled and run this code have you. You're dereferencing a null pointer: `emp` is initialized to NULL (static storage), and it's a pointer. You're not allocating the memory for the struct anywhere, so `(*record)->id` is like writing `(NULL)->id`, which is of course wrong

Comment: I have compiled and there's shows nothing wrong with code. whenever i try to take input it stop working and exit the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A double pointer is not needed. You can accomplish this with single pointer as well. You would however need to allocate memory for the structure before populating it.

`struct employee *emp = malloc(sizeof(struct employee));`

Also the size of `char addr[]` in your structure is undefined. That needs to be allocated separately similar to:

`emp->addr = malloc(N*sizeof(*emp->addr));`

All other fields in the structure which has a fixed size such as integer,float and a character array of 20 elements does not need allocation. The allocation for them would be done by malloc we did earlier. However since `addr` is a pointer, memory equivalent to size of pointer would be reserved for it. To store anything in the address the `addr` points to, we need to allocate.

Afterwards pass emp to your function. Remove the double pointer

Comment: ***Don't*** cast the return value of `malloc`. Also: `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, no point in adding that. The preferred way to allocate memory is: `some_ptr = malloc(N * sizeof *some_ptr);` Because it does what it's supposed to, always: `malloc` N times the size of the the type `some_ptr` points to. `some_ptr` can change type, the `malloc` call will still work. regardless of the levels of indirection you're dealing with, using the `sizeof *destination_ptr` will _always_ work

Comment: Thanks. I'll make the correction. That's a very beneficial advice

Comment: Thanks sharad and elias. It was all about memory allocation to structure pointer. what is good code to get input as  **scanf("%d",(*record)->id)** , **scanf("%d",&record->id)** and **scanf("%d",record->id)** works all fine.

Comment: If you are using single pointer then scanf("%d",&record->id) is correct